# Pass HAProxy healthcheck requests as User-agent "LB-Check" to the backend webservers (apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, haproxy

I have a HAProxy setup in front of Apache webservers for load balancing. Health checks for these webservers are also configured in HAProxy.

```
option httpchk  HEAD /healthcheck.txt HTTP/1.0
```

Is it possible to transfer these health check requests to backend webservers as `LB-Check`, `User-agent` or any other option, so that I can distinguish them from other log entries?

(I don't want to go for the `dontlog`" option, as I don't want to miss these entries.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you're already requesting what i assume to be a unique file name for the health check, so why do you need something else?

but to answer your question, you can abuse the HTTP/1.0 bit as follows:

```
option httpchk HEAD /healthcheck.txt HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-agent:\ LB-Check
```

Answer (score 3):

Few years later and it is supported by HAProxy directly:

```
option httpchk
http-check send hdr User-Agent "LB-Check" hdr Host example.com meth HEAD uri /healthcheck.txt
```

https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#4-http-check%20send